# Trying to find the intervall onto which cosh(x) is strictly increasing

Tags: inequality, hyperbolic-functions

I tried to find the interval onto which cosh(x) is strictly increasing:
\begin{array}{c}
cosh(x) < cosh(x+1) \\
\frac{1}{2}(e^x+\frac{1}{e^x})<\frac{1}{2}(e^{x+1}+\frac{1}{e^{x+1}})\qquad |*2\\
e^x+\frac{1}{e^x}<e^{x+1}+\frac{1}{e^{x+1}} \qquad | -e^{x+1}-\frac{1}{e^{x+1}}\\
e^x-e^{x+1}+\frac{1}{e^x}-\frac{1}{e^{x+1}}<0\\
e^x(1-e)+\frac{1}{e^x}(1-\frac{1}{e})<0 \qquad |*e^x\\
e^{2x}(1-e)+(1-\frac{1}{e})<0\\
e^{2x}(1-e)+1-\frac{1}{e}<0\qquad |-1+\frac{1}{e}\\
e^{2x}(1-e)<\frac{1}{e}-1 \qquad |:(1-e)\\
e^{2x}>(\frac{1}{e}-1)\frac{1}{1-e} = \frac{1-e}{e} \frac{1}{1-e} = \frac{1}{e}=e^{-1}\\
2x>-1\qquad |:2\\
x>-\frac{1}{2}
\end{array}
But this is obviously wrong, it should be:
\begin{array}{c}
 x>0\\
\end{array}
Where is my mistake?

Comment: The fact that the function at $x+1$ is larger than the function at $x$ does not mean it is increasing. For example, for the function $f(x)=x^2$, it is true that $f(-0.25)<f(0.75)$, though the function is not increasing at $x=-0.25$.

Comment: Your mistake lies in the first line. It is not true that $\cosh(x) < \cosh(x+1)$ for all $x$. It is also not enough to assume this. Is $f(x)$ increasing on all of $[0,1]$ if $f(0) = 1$, $f(0.5) = -12$, and $f(1) = 4$? Your method would suggest that it is, but it is obviously not

Comment: If you want to find where $f(x)$ is increasing and $f$ is differentiable, find the $x$ such that $f'(x) > 0$.

Comment: Why would you pick $x$ and $x+1$? What about $x+\frac12$? Or $x+\epsilon$ for any small positive $\epsilon$?